# Exchange 2013 Mail flow rule using RegEx

Tags: exchange, email-server, regex, exchange-2013

We're trying to implement a rule on certain mailboxes that it shouldn't accept an email without a subject.

I found documentation from Microsoft on exchange 2010 to [Configure a Transport Rule for Messages That Have a Blank Subject](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb430785%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx), but I tried using the `^$` RegEx with Exchange 2013 and it doesn't seem to work.

I also looked at the [Transport Rule Predicates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919235%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) for Exchange 2013 and it clearly says that `SubjectMatchesPatterns matches messages where text patterns in the Subject field match a specified regular expression`.

My workaround was to reject all messages to those specific mailboxes except if subject pattern matches `.` but if I want to add now conditions ie. to reject emails with a subject "Sent from my snipping tool" I can't do it.

I found that Exchange 2013 now supports extended RegEx but I didn't find that the syntax for `^$` should be any different in extended RegEx.